# Pandas groupby.agg cannot handle returned tuples when passing extra argument

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

Assume that I want to aggregate my grouped data into tuples through a function that takes extra arguments. Normally, I supply an extra argument `y` as in `df.groupby(col).agg(my_fun, y)`. This works fine when `my_fun` returns a scalar but throws an error when it returns a `tuple`. However, passing the extra arguments with `df.groupby(col).agg(lambda x: my_fun(x, y))` works. Why is this happening and is this intentional behavior?

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(4)), list(range(1, 5))])
print(df)

    0   1   2   3
-----------------
0|  0   1   2   3
1|  1   2   3   4
```

Create a groupby object and define aggregating functions:

```
g = df.groupby(0)

def scalar1(x):
    return 1

def scalar2(x, y):
    return 1 + y

def tuple1(x):
    return (1, 2)

def tuple2(x, y):
    return (1 + y, 2)
```

Now let's apply these functions; the first three works just as expected:

```
g.agg(scalar1)
    1   2   3
-------------       
0|  1   1   1
1|  1   1   1

g.agg(scalar2, 4)
    1   2   3
-------------       
0|  5   5   5
1|  5   5   5

g.agg(tuple1)
      1        2      3
--------------------------      
0   (1, 2)  (1, 2)  (1, 2)
1   (1, 2)  (1, 2)  (1, 2)
```

But the last one raises `ValueError: ...`:

```
g.agg(tuple2, 4)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (3, 2)
```

However, using a lambda is fine:

```
g.agg(lambda x: tuple2(x, 4))
      1        2      3
--------------------------      
0   (5, 2)  (5, 2)  (5, 2)
1   (5, 2)  (5, 2)  (5, 2)
```